# Auto fill multiple text fields using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a form, which I have divided in to there parts using  tabs, in my second tab I'm using a select option  and then try to auto fill 2 text box's and one text area using Ajax ,but although console log shows that ajax return the object but it doesn't fill the required fields.

tab

```
<div class="tab-pane fade " id="package_details">
```

select option

```
<select name="package"  id="packageid" >             
 <option  selected >  Select a Package  </option>        
  @foreach($package as $c)
 <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->tour_name}}</option>
   @endforeach
  </select>
```

Text fields i need auto filling

```
<input type="number" name="no_of_days" id="no_of_days" class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Days" >
<input type="number" name="cost" id="cost" class="form-control"
                                     placeholder="Price" >
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"  class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder=" Package Details"  ></textarea>
```

my Ajax code

```
$(document).on('change', '#packageid', function(e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var pkid = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
          url: "{{ route('package.tour') }}",
          dataType: "json",
         data:{
       '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),        
       'selectedid': pkid
        },
        success: function(data){
           // console.log(data);
          $('#description').val(data.description);
          $('#no_of_days').val(data.no_of_days);
          $('#cost').val(data.cost);

           }

      });
    });
```

Function in my controller

```
public function getPackage(Request $request)
    {
        $data = packages::where('id', $request->selectedid)->get();

                 return response()->json($data);
    }
```

what is wrong with my `Ajax` / `JQuery` code ?

Answer (score 0):

check using like this in ajax response :

```
   $("textarea#description").val(data.description);

   $("input#no_of_days").val(data.no_of_days);

   $("input#cost").val(data.cost);
```

Comment: Did that but still doesn't fill the fields :(

Comment: Which field is creating issue?
All of them or particular

Comment: in console log  :  Array(1)

__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Will you be able to share your console complete value ?

Comment: Array(1)
0: {id: 1, tour_name: "Sigiri -Dambulla Cultural Tour", description: "DAY 01 - Pickup from the airport  and arrival at t…h .
↵DAY 07 - Colombo city tour and airport drop.", no_of_days: 7, cost: "360.00", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: There is issue in your response.

Comment: Let me show you one example, how it should look like : 
{type: "success", message: "1 Emails added in list. "}
message: "1 Emails added in list. "
type: "success"
__proto__: Object

Comment: json_encode( array("type"=>"success", "description" => "DESCRIPTION SHOULD BE HERE", "no_of_days" => 6, "cost" => 300) )

Comment: your return value should look like this

Comment: Check using this code in your function : 

public function getPackage(Request $request)
    {
        $data = packages::where('id', $request->selectedid)->get();

                 return json_encode( array("type"=>"success", "description" => "DESCRIPTION SHOULD BE HERE", "no_of_days" => 6, "cost" => 300) );
    }

And let me know if it works

Comment: great!! now please show me this return value : 

echo response()->json($data);

Comment: That might be the issue, you can set error if empty record : 

return json_encode( array("type"=>"error", "message" => "No record found") );

And in ajax response : 
if(data.type == "success"){
  $("textarea#description").val(data.description);

   $("input#no_of_days").val(data.no_of_days);

   $("input#cost").val(data.cost);
}else{
  $(#error_div).html("<div class='alert alert-warning'>"+data.message+"</div>")
}

Comment: your return value should not be empty or should look like this : 
 array("type"=>"success", "description" => "DESCRIPTION SHOULD BE HERE", "no_of_days" => 6, "cost" => 300)

Comment: Thanks let me try , btw i think type success part is always not included in my response object why is that?

Comment: Yes, that is only to check whether response is empty or not .

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out ,since response is an array i had to use $("#description").val(data[0].description); and it works !

Comment: If 'id' is primary key in your table then you should do  packages::find($request->selectedid); or packages::where('id', $request->selectedid)->first(); it will return single object instead of array so you don't need to provide index while assign value in javascript. you can do $("#description").val(data.description); instead of $("#description").val(data[0].description);